# Discord Bot Python send a message every hour

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with discord's bot.
I have done a script which calculate the weather every hour and I want to send the result to discord with bot:

```
import Secret
import discord
result = "temp is ...."

TOKEN = Secret.BOT_TOKEN
client = discord.Client()

client.send(result)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I have searched on google but I have not found an answer to send the result automatically.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python just put it in a while loop and have it send the message and sleep for an hour.

for sleep you can `import time`

Something like:

```
while true:
    client.send(result)
    sleep(3600)
```

**Important:**
Your bot will be 100% inactive while you sleep it, so if you use it for more than just weather this might not be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I have already a code for receive weather but i can send on my discord with bot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but either way just throw it in an infinite loop and sleep it for 3600 seconds after you send the weather data.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `time` module prevents your bot from doing anything else during the time that it is sleeping.

Use tasks. Just put what you want executed in the `task()` function:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks 

@tasks.loop(seconds=60) # repeat once every 60 seconds
async def task():
  pass

mytask.start()
```